# Totalling Columns by a common suffix in SAS

Tags: function, sas, sum

I have a series of Columns titled `Income_2015`, `Interest 2015`, `Dividends 2015`, `Income_2018`, `Interest 2018`, `Dividends 2018` etc and want to create total columns for each year.

Is there a way to do this in SAS without having to individually list all of the columns in the sum

I currently use the following to get totals by type:

```
data keep;
set from;

income_total = sum(of Income_:);
run;
```

I cannot find a way to total by year unless I use:

```
year_2015_total = sum(Income_2015, Interest_2015, Dividends_2015)
```

....
`year_2018_total = sum(Income_2018, Interest_2018, Dividends_2018)`

I appreciate that I could do the above but this is just an sample of the columns I need to include. The actual list is far longer

Comment: How wide (how many variables) is the actual row ?  Did you create the wide row structure ? The wide data structure in the question has data (year) in the metadata (column names).  Is the original data (`id`, `category`, `year` and `amount`) available in categorical form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an easy / automatic way to define a variable list by the suffix.  That is, there is nothing directly equivalent to `sum (of :2018)`.

That said, you have options.  One is to use arrays.  They allow you to reference a list of variables by the array name.

Another is to use the macro language.  That will allow you to build a macro variable that holds the list of all variable names that have a particular suffix.

But I think the best solution is to restructure your data.

If your data now looks like:

```
Person Income_2015 Interest_2015 Income_2016 Interest_2016
1      100,000     1,000         200,000     2,000
2      500,000     5,000         600,000     6,000
```

Transpose it to:

```
Person Year        Income      Interest
1      2015        100,000     1,000
1      2016        200,000     2,000
2      2015        500,000     5,000
2      2016        600,000     6,000
```

That vertical structure makes it *much* easier to work with the data, and you can easily aggregate across years (columns) or income sources (rows).  The key point is that year is really a data value.  So the vertical ("normalized") structure benefits you by storing year as a value in a variable, instead of storing year as part of a variable name.

Comment: Thanks. I had the feeling I wasn't going to be able to solve it the way I had envisaged. You're right transposing the values is the simplest way to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use macro variables,such as:

```
proc sql;
    select name into:list_2015 separated by ',' from dictionary.columns where libname='YOURLIB' and memname='YOURDATA' and name contains '2015';
quit;

data want;
  set have;
  sum_2015=sum(of &list_2015);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data design has unfortunately stored the data element  as part of the metadata (a portion of variable name(s)) and you get a data set that becomes wide.

The categorical form is suited for roll up aggregations, and use of reporting procedures such as `TABULATE` or `REPORT` to generate the 'wide' view of the data.

```
id topic     year  amount
a  income    2015  
a  interest  2015  
a  dividends 2015
a  losses    2015
b  income    2015  
b  interest  2015  
b  dividends 2015
                    … no losses row for id=b corresponds to 'missing' value in wide form
c  income    2015  
c  interest  2015  
                    … c had no dividends, no losses, no fubars
```

Keeping the structure unchanged (some times you just have to, like mainframe data of ten-million accounts spanning 60 years), you would need to preprocess the data set with a step that identifies the columns containing a year like value and use that information in a subsequent step code which contains code generation (i.e. macro) that covers the years as found in the column names.  For example:

```
%macro make_data(data=);
  %local year category index varname;

  data &data;
    do accountid = 1 to 20;
      %do index = 65 %to 90;
      %do year=1995 %to 2019;
        %let varname = %sysfunc(byte(&index))_&year;
        amount+1;
        &varname = amount;
      %end;
      %end;
      output;
    end;
    drop amount;
  run;
%mend;

%macro generate_year_total_code(data=);
  proc contents noprint data=&data out=havemeta(keep=name);
  run;

  data havemeta2;
    set havemeta;
    if prxmatch ("/[^0-9]\d{4}/", trim(name));
    year = input(substr(name,length(name)-3), 4.);
  run;

  proc sort data=havemeta2;
    by year;
  run;

  data _null_;
    length varlist $32000;

    do until (last.year);
      set havemeta2;
      by year;

      varlist = catx(',', varlist, name);
    end;

    call symputx('year_count', _n_);
    call symput ( cats('total_statement_', _n_)
                , cats('total_',year,'=sum(',varlist,')'));
  run;
%mend;

%macro totals(data=);

  %generate_year_total_code(data=&data);

  %local index; 

  data &data;
    set &data;
    %do index = 1 %to &year_count;
      &&total_statement_&index;
    %end;
  run;

%mend;

%make_data(data=have);

options mprint;
%totals(data=have);
```

An alternative is to transpose the data into categorical form in order to extract the year value for appropriate roll up or use in categorical reporting. For example:

```
proc transpose data=have out=haveTall;
  by accountid;
run;

data haveTall;
    set haveTall;
    if prxmatch ("/_\d{4}$/", trim(_name_));  * data value in col1 is from a year suffixed variable name;
    year = input(substr(_name_,length(_name_)-3), 4.);
    category = substr(_name_,1, length(_name_)-5);
    amount = col1;
    drop _name_ col1;
run;

proc tabulate data=haveTall;
  class accountid category year;
  var amount;
  table 
    accountid * category
    , 
    year=''*amount=''*sum=''
    /
    nocellmerge
    ;
run;
```

A third more complex, but succinct, way.  Dynamically compute the totals using a hash object, output the totals and merge back to your original data.  This requires more cpu than way #1 because the PDV variable names are evaluated in each row.

```
data _null_;
  if 0 then set have(keep=accountid);

  length year amount 8;
  declare hash totals(ordered:'a');
  totals.defineKey('accountid', 'year');
  totals.defineData('accountid', 'year', 'total');
  totals.defineDone();
  call missing (year, amount, accountid);

  do until (end);
    set have end=end;
    array numbers _numeric_;

    do over numbers;
      length name $32;
      name = vname(numbers);
      if prxmatch ("/_\d{4}$/", trim(name)) then do;
        year = input(substr(name,length(name)-3), 4.);
        if totals.find() = 0
          then total + numbers;
          else total = numbers;
        totals.replace();
      end;
    end;
  end;

  totals.output(dataset:'totals');

  stop;
run;

proc transpose data=totals prefix=total_ out=totals_across_year(drop=_name_);
  by accountid;
  var total;
  id year;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. Yours is a far more comprehensive solution than I was looking for on the occasion but I will look to implement it in other projects I'm working on